# How can I remove all files "added by them"?

Tags: git, merge

Instead of `git rm $(git ls-files -z -d)` I need `git rm $(git ls-files -z -u)` but it doesn't work and I think it's because `-u` adds other garbage to the output instead of only the filenames as with the other switches. Is there an alternative way? I just want to remove all files that git lists as "added by them" in the "unmerged paths" section (these are the only ones in that section, therefore `-u`) of git status.

Answer (score 0):

you can pipe the output to `cut` or `sed` to take specific parts of the output of a command. Otherwise, git also provides the `--raw` or `--porcelain` options to form the output in a script-friendly syntax.